# Error 500 when deployed on Vercel but working in local

Tags: next.js, vercel

I keep getting getting error 500 | internal server error on vercel but my project work perfectly in localhost.
I haven't changed anything that seem concerned by that error and even when I try to go back to a previous version that worked, I keep getting the problem

I have that error in the vercel logs:

````
    '/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js',
    '/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js',
    '/var/task/___next_launcher.cjs'
  ],
  page: '/'
}
Error: Cannot find module 'core-js/modules/es.array.map.js'
Require stack:
- /var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/config/createConfig.js
- /var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/appWithTranslation.js
- /var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/index.js
- /var/task/.next/server/pages/_app.js
- /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js
- /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js
- /var/task/___next_launcher.cjs
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:54:36
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Ze.e.<computed>._module.Module._load (/var/task/___vc/__launcher/__launcher.js:14:1964)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at mod.require (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:64:28)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/config/createConfig.js:35:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/config/createConfig.js',
    '/var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/appWithTranslation.js',
    '/var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/index.js',
    '/var/task/.next/server/pages/_app.js',
    '/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js',
    '/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js',
    '/var/task/___next_launcher.cjs'
  ]
}
Error: Cannot find module 'core-js/modules/es.array.map.js'
Require stack:
- /var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/config/createConfig.js
- /var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/appWithTranslation.js
- /var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/index.js
- /var/task/.next/server/pages/_app.js
- /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js
- /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js
- /var/task/___next_launcher.cjs
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:54:36
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Ze.e.<computed>._module.Module._load (/var/task/___vc/__launcher/__launcher.js:14:1964)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at mod.require (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:64:28)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/config/createConfig.js:35:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/config/createConfig.js',
    '/var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/appWithTranslation.js',
    '/var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/index.js',
    '/var/task/.next/server/pages/_app.js',
    '/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js',
    '/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js',
    '/var/task/___next_launcher.cjs'
  ],
  page: '/'
}
Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason
Runtime.ExitError```
````

Comment: Wish node version are you using? wich version of nextjs ? have you try to run the project in prod environement locally ?

Comment: We also use `next-i18next`, and we are getting the same error today after a deploy. The deploy was unrelated to `next-i18next`. Maybe is a Vercel issue, as we run the same code on other platform and we don't get this problem there.

Comment: My deploy wasn't related to next-i18next either.
I still can't figure out wat the problème is.
Let me know if find a solution

"next": "^13.5.3"
"@types/node": "20.8.0"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an issue between `next` v13.5.4 and `next-i18next` at the moment.

Be sure Next.js is v13.5.3 (including in your `package-lock.json`).

I faced the same issue and solved it by pinning next to v13.5.3 in my `package.json` (like from `"next": "^13.5.3"` to `"next": "13.5.3"`, no caret sign).

In my case, I previously did run `npm audit fix` that updated my `package-lock.json` with next v13.5.4, and that caused the problem.

This seems the way of avoid this issue until `next` or `next-i18next` have a fix for it.

Comment: It was indeed the problem, thank you so much